# Change font in network plot

Tags: r

**Problem:**

I am using the [network package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/network/index.html) in [R](https://www.r-project.org) and want to change the labels font to bold.

**Example:**

```
library(network)
set.seed(42)
m<-matrix(rbinom(100,1,1.5/9),10)
diag(m)<-0
g<-network(m)
plot(g, displaylabels=T)
```

[image]

**Question:**

The [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/network/network.pdf) and associated ressources (i.e. [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/network/vignettes/networkVignette.pdf)) do not provide any hint. How can I tweak the plot so that the labels appear in **bold** font? A solution within the premises ([network package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/network/index.html) in [R](https://www.r-project.org)) is required.

Comment: Run `par(font=2)` before plotting, and you'll get bold labels. `par(font=1)` to go back to plain text. See `?par` for more on graphical parameters.

Comment: Thx, that was a quick one :-). Please provide an answer to give you full credit. Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `par(font=2)` before plotting, and you'll get bold labels. `par(font=1)` to go back to plain text. See `?par` for more on graphical parameters.

Comment: Also check out `par(family="Arial Black")` for whatever font you want to use.  "Arial Black" seems to make the text bigger and bold.